# How to test a maven plugin using JUnit4

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, junit4

I'm writing a maven plugin and want to write some JUnit tests. I followed the description in [Maven Plugin Testing](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html). Unfortunately I keep getting an Exception during set-up of the test, before I can configure or invoke anything.

This is my JUnit test code:

```
public class ResetMojoTest {

    private static final String POM_FILE_NAME = "/path/to/pom.xml"; 

    @Rule
    public MojoRule rule = new MojoRule();

    @Test
    public void testSomething()
        throws Exception
    {
        File pom = new File(POM_FILE_NAME);
        Assert.assertNotNull( pom );
        Assert.assertTrue( pom.exists() );

        ResetMojo resetMojo = (ResetMojo) rule.lookupMojo( "touch", pom );
        Assert.assertNotNull( resetMojo );
        resetMojo.execute();
    }

}
```

And this is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:134)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream.getBOM(BOMInputStream.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream.getBOMCharsetName(BOMInputStream.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.XmlStreamReader.doRawStream(XmlStreamReader.java:412)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.XmlStreamReader.<init>(XmlStreamReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.XmlStreamReader.<init>(XmlStreamReader.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.XmlStreamReader.<init>(XmlStreamReader.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.MojoRule$2.evaluate(MojoRule.java:299)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
```

Any ideas about how to get this working?

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

Also experiencing this issue. The mojo rule fails, because it instantiates a an anonymous implementation of `AbstractMojoTestCase`, which then looks for which then attempts to create an input stream loading data here: `InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/" + getPluginDescriptorLocation() );`. This (`getPluginDescriptorLocation()`) is just a hard-coded file string `"META-INF/maven/plugin.xml"`.

I resolved this by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure why this fixes the issue. The file still doesn't exist (I've checked both original sources and `target` directories and it's not in either). So additional searching will be needed to figure out why this works.

Here's my dependencies for reference.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
  <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<!--Test Dependencies-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue. Solved it by adding the right dependencies. Important is that the dependencies marked as provided by the harness maven plugin are added to test scope:

```
<properties>
  <dependency.maven.version>3.3.9</dependency.maven.version>
  <!-- and others -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <!-- your dependencies -->

  <!-- maven plugin dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- test dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.maven.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- provided maven dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And your Test class should look like

```
public class YourMojoTest {

  @Rule
  public MojoRule rule = new MojoRule();

  @Test
  public void shouldExecuteMojo() throws Exception {
    // given
    File testPom = new File(PlexusTestCase.getBasedir(), "src/test/resources/pom.xml");

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    final MavenProject mavenProject = Mockito.mock(MavenProject.class);
    Mockito.when(mavenProject.getProperties()).thenReturn(properties);

    // when
    YourMojo mojo = (YourMojo) rule.lookupMojo("fetch", testPom);
    assertNotNull(mojo);
    mojo.setProject(mavenProject);
    mojo.execute();

    // then
    // do your tests ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps for other struggling with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Got this fixed by adding maven compatability library:-

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

The loading of the POM file does not look good:

The following code is from the examples:

```
File pom = rule.getTestFile( "src/test/resources/unit/project-to-test/pom.xml" );
```

and this is what you have:

```
File pom = new File(POM_FILE_NAME);
```

Apart from this you have a different location which looks like this:

```
private static final String POM_FILE_NAME = "/path/to/pom.xml";
```

But the location of the pom file should be:

```
private static final String POM_FILE_NAME = "src/test/resources/pom.xml";
```

Comment: Yes, the example does not compile. But that's not relevant anyway. If you have a look at the stack trace you can see that it crashes much earlier. The test method is never executed.

Comment: And that means what? This code does not get executed. It's the `MojoRule` set-up that's crashing.

Comment: Where is you pom file really located? The path you have used looks wrong cause it starts with `/...`..

Comment: The method `getTestFile` does not exist on the [MojoRule Class](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/testing/MojoRule.html). There is even a [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPLUGINTESTING-34) stating that the example documentation is wrong.

Comment: Worse, the bug is closed, and not fixed like the comments claim!